# Laravel mail cannot send from field

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

Im trying to send mail from laravel and when i add the dynamic from field i get  this error:

"Expected response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 A syntax error was encountered in command argument.."

this is the code:

```
$user = Input::get('user'); 
Mail::send('template.contact',  $user , function($message) use ($user)
{
    $email = $user['email'];
    $message->from($email , 'name'); thats doesnt
    //$message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel'); that work

    $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'contact us' )->subject($user['subject']);
});
```

and the user is coming from angular -
service:

```
 this.sendConatctMail = function(data) {
        return $http.post('send-contact-mail', {user: data});
      }
```

and controller:

```
contactService.sendConatctMail($scope.user);
```

Comment: `var_dump` the `$user` before `Mail::send`

Comment: Can you show the code that is making the ajax request?

Comment: is `data` on `this.sendConatctMail = function(data) {` a javascript array or a object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can solve this.

Let's assume the `data` on `this.sendConatctMail = function(data) {` is a object like this:

```
var data {
    email: 'some@email.com',
    // other field: values
}
```

Right before you post it, you should convert it into JSON string like this:

```
return $http.post('send-contact-mail', {user: JSON.stringify(data)});
```

Then on Laravel/PHP side, decode that back into an `array` and use it like this:

```
if (Input::has('user'))
{
    // Decode json string
    $user = @json_decode(Input::get('user'), true);

    // Proceed if json decoding was success
    if ($user)
    {
        // send email
        Mail::send('template.contact',  $user , function($message) use (&$user)
        {
            $message->from($user['email'], 'name')
                    ->to('test@gmail.com', 'contact us')
                    ->subject($user['subject']);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Now im getting this error :Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object give. it expect array and you convert it to object.

Comment: Ah, easy fix. You probably want to decode the JSON string back into an array, rather than an object. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but whenever I send emails through Laravel, I need to alter the `use(...)` section a bit. You have:

```
$user = Input::get('user'); 
Mail::send('template.contact',  $user , function($message) use ($user)
...
```

Try changing it to this and see what happens:

```
$user = Input::get('user'); 
Mail::send('template.contact',  array('user' => $user), function($message) use (&$user) {
  $message->from($user['email'], $user['name']);
  $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'contact us')->subject($user['subject']);
}
```

2 changes I made:

```
array('user' => $user)
```

and

```
use(&$user)
```

I don't know if that will help you, but I have working emails on my application that look almost identical to yours, except for the `&$variable` instead of just `$variable`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your  `$email = $user['email'];`

try checking your `$user['email']`

if `$message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');` this works

then

```
$email = $user['email'];
$message->from($email , 'name');
```

this must work...

I have tried the same without much trouble...

In my application I needed to pass the `_token` variable in all my ajax request any such problems??

Comment: When i var dump the $user['email'] im getting the right string but its still give me this error